# unable to install php 7.2 in my ubuntu 14.04 repo error occred

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7.2

I am unable to install php 7.2 on my Ubuntu 14.04

```
root@OD033:/etc/php# sudo apt-get install php7.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'
root@OD033:/etc/php#
```

Comment: Duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/873768/how-do-i-install-php7-on-ubuntu-14-04/873803 . Also please use https://askubuntu.com/ for Ubuntu specific questions

Answer (score 1):

Do not add version, simply run `sudo apt install php` it would install latest. if you want add versions in apt install do as below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

then you will be able to install whatever version you need to.

Comment: getting issue

dev32@OD032:~$ sudo apt install php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php is a virtual package provided by:
  php5.6 5.6.33-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.1 7.1.27-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'php' has no installation candidate

Comment: did you test these lines:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update

Answer (score 0):

Currently the ondrej repositories does not support Ubuntu 14.04 as it reached end of life thus you cannot use them. You can either compile from source or upgrade your distribution.

Comment: Is there a way to install php7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04?